# Why primary key is getting repeated in the child tables as foreign key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am going nuts and I mean i cannot figure out since so many days what's happening.

Client is using this and inserting data in to the tables.

EQ_HEADER is the table and after puting data into that we take it's PRIMARY key EQ_HEADERID and put in other tables.

But PROBLEM is

In some cases.... the PRIMARY KEY that we get from PARENT table is getting duplicated in the all other child tables even the EQUIPMENTNO is different. It's 1 to 1 only but why HEADERID is getting repeated in many cases?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertEquipmentsDATA]
                                    
        @FunctionalLocation varchar(30)= null   ,
        @EquipmentNo    varchar(30) = null  ,
        
        @IsGeneralEmpty bit=0,
        @ANSDTSpecified bit= null,
        @ANSDT_General  date= null,
        @ANSWT_General  varchar(13)= null,      
        @BAUJJ_General  varchar(4)= null,
        @BAUMM_General  varchar(2)= null,
        @BEGRU_General  varchar(4)= null,
        @EQART_General  varchar(10)= null,
        @ERDAT_General  date= null,
        @ERDATSpecified bit= null,
        @HERLD_General  varchar(3)= null,
        @HZEIN_General varchar(30)= null,
        @HERST_General  varchar(30)= null,
        @INBDT_General  date= null,
        @INBDTSpecified bit= null,
        @SERGE_General  varchar(30)= null,
        @TYPBZ_General  varchar(20)= null,

        @IsHeaderEmpty bit=0,
        @DATAB_Header date= null,
        @DATABSpecified bit= null,
        @DATABI_Header date= null,
        @DATABISpecified bit= null,
        @EQTYP varchar(1)= null,
        @EQUNR varchar(18)= null,
        @GUID_Header  varchar(36)= null,
        @SHTXT_Header varchar(40)= null,
        @STTXT_Header varchar(4)= null,

        @IsLocationEmpty bit=0,
        @ABCKZ_Location varchar(1)= null,
        @BEBER_Location varchar(3)= null,
        @EQFNR_Location varchar(30)= null,
        @MSGRP_Location varchar(8)= null,
        @STORT_Location varchar(10)= null,
        @SWERK_Location varchar(4)= null,

        @IsOrganizationEmpty bit= 0,
        @ANLNR_Organizations varchar(12)= null,
        @BUKRS_Organizations varchar(4)= null,
        @GEWRK_Organizations varchar(20)= null,
        @GSBER_Organizations varchar(4)= null,
        @INGRP_Organizations varchar(3)= null,
        @IWERK_Organizations varchar(4)= null,
        @KOKRS_Organizations varchar(4)= null,
        @KOSTL_Organizations varchar(10)= null,
        @PROID_Organizations varchar(20)= null,
        @RBNR_Organizations varchar(9)= null,

        --@ATINN_Classification int,
        --@ATWRT_Classification varchar(70),

        @IsStructureEmpty bit=0,
        @HEQNR_Structure varchar(4)= null,
        @HEQUI_Structure varchar(18)= null,
        @POSNR_Structure varchar(4)= null,
        @SUBMT_Structure varchar(40)= null,
        @TIDNR_Structure varchar(25)= null,
        @TPLNR_Structure varchar(40)= null,

        @ATNAM_Characteristic   varchar(50)= null,
        @ATZHL_Characteristic   varchar(3)= null,
        @ATBEZ_Characteristic   varchar(40)= null,
    
        @ATWRT_Value    varchar(40)= null,
        @EINHE_Value    varchar(6)= null ,
        @ATZHL_Value    varchar(3)= null ,

        @IsSerialEmpty bit= 0,
        @B_CHARGE   varchar(10)= null,
        @B_LAGER    varchar(4)= null,
        @B_WERK varchar(4)= null       ,
        @CHARGE varchar(10) = null   ,
        @LBBSA  varchar(2)  = null   ,
        @MATNR  varchar(40)  = null  ,
        @SERNR  varchar(18)  = null  ,

        @IsWarrantyEmpty bit= 0,
        @GWLDT  date= null     ,
        @GWLDTSpecified bit= null,
        @GWLEN  date    = null   ,
        @GWLENSpecified bit= null,
    
        @ClassificationCollection Classification readonly, 
        @CharacteristicCollection Characteristic readonly, 
        @ValueCollection Value readonly,  

        @StatusRet varchar(20) out,
        @ErrorRet varchar(1000) out 

AS
BEGIN

    Begin Try
       
        Begin Transaction
        Declare @Status Char(1)
        SET @Status='N'
            IF exists (Select * from EQ_Header where EQUNR= @EQUNR) 
            Begin
                    Set @StatusRet= 'Change'
                    Set @ErrorRet= ''
                    SET @Status='U'
            End
                
            --      --Update EQ_Header
            --      --Set
            --      --  EquipmentNo     = @EquipmentNo  ,
            --      --  DATAB           = @DATAB_Header,
            --      --  DATABSpecified  = @DATABSpecified   ,
            --      --  DATBI           = @DATABI_Header    ,
            --      --  DATBISpecified  = @DATABISpecified  ,
            --      --  EQTYP           = @EQTYP            ,
            --      --  EQUNR           = @EQUNR            ,
            --      --  SHTXT           = @SHTXT_Header     ,
            --      --  STTXT           = @STTXT_Header     

            --      --where EQUNR= @EQUNR
                    
            --      Set @STATUSRet= 'Change'
            --      Set @ErrorRet= (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())

            --  Commit
            --  return

            --End

            Insert into FunctionalLocations
            (           
                FunctionalLocation
            )
            values
            (
                @FunctionalLocation
            )

            Insert into [dbo].[Equipment]
            (
                EquipmentNo,
                FunctionalLocation,
                Status
            )
            values 
            (
                @EQUNR,
                @FunctionalLocation,
                'Pending'
            )

            
            IF(@IsHeaderEmpty = 0)
            Begin
                Insert into [dbo].[EQ_Header]
                (

                    EquipmentNo     ,
                    DATAB           ,
                    DATABSpecified  ,
                    DATBI           ,
                    DATBISpecified  ,
                    EQTYP           ,
                    EQUNR           ,
                    SHTXT           ,
                    STTXT,
                    GUID,
                    Status,
                    Transferred

                )
                values 
                (
                    @EquipmentNo        ,
                    @DATAB_Header ,
                    @DATABSpecified ,
                    @DATABI_Header ,
                    @DATABISpecified ,
                    @EQTYP ,
                    @EQUNR ,
                    @SHTXT_Header,
                    @STTXT_Header,
                    @GUID_Header,
                    @Status,
                    0
                )
            End

            Declare @HeaderID int
            Set @HeaderID= IDENT_CURRENT('EQ_Header') --Latest Header ID

            IF(@IsGeneralEmpty = 0)
            Begin
                Insert into [dbo].[EQ_General]
            (   
                
                EquipmentNo ,
                ANSDT           ,
                ANSDTSpecified  ,
                ANSWT           ,
                BAUJJ           ,
                BAUMM           ,
                BEGRU           ,
                EQART           ,
                ERDAT           ,
                ERDATSpecified  ,
                HERLD           ,
                HERST           ,
                HZEIN           ,
                INBDT           ,
                INBDTSpecified  ,
                SERGE           ,
                TYPBZ       ,
                HeaderID                                                
            )
            values 
            (
                @EquipmentNo ,
                @ANSDT_General  ,
                @ANSDTSpecified ,
                @ANSWT_General  ,
                @BAUJJ_General  ,
                @BAUMM_General  ,
                @BEGRU_General  ,
                @EQART_General  ,
                @ERDAT_General  ,
                @ERDATSpecified ,
                @HERLD_General  ,
                @HERST_General  ,
                @HZEIN_General,
                @INBDT_General  ,
                @INBDTSpecified ,
                @SERGE_General  ,
                @TYPBZ_General  ,
                @HeaderID
            )
            End


            IF(@IsLocationEmpty = 0)
            Begin
                Insert into [dbo].[EQ_Location]
                (
                    EquipmentNo,
                    ABCKZ      ,
                    BEBER      ,
                    EQFNR      ,
                    MSGRP      ,
                    STORT      ,
                    SWERK,
                    HeaderID

                )
                values 
                (
                    @EquipmentNo,
                    @ABCKZ_Location    ,
                    @BEBER_Location    ,
                    @EQFNR_Location    ,
                    @MSGRP_Location    ,
                    @STORT_Location    ,
                    @SWERK_Location,
                    @HeaderID
                )
            End
          
            IF(@IsOrganizationEmpty = 0)
            Begin
                Insert into [dbo].[EQ_Organizations]
                (
                    EquipmentNo,
                    ANLNR       ,
                    BUKRS       ,
                    GEWRK       ,
                    GSBER       ,
                    INGRP       ,
                    IWERK       ,
                    KOKRS       ,
                    KOSTL       ,
                    PROID       ,
                    RBNR        ,
                    HeaderID        
                
                )
                values 
                (
                    @EquipmentNo,
                    @ANLNR_Organizations        ,
                    @BUKRS_Organizations        ,
                    @GEWRK_Organizations        ,
                    @GSBER_Organizations        ,
                    @INGRP_Organizations        ,
                    @IWERK_Organizations        ,
                    @KOKRS_Organizations        ,
                    @KOSTL_Organizations        ,
                    @PROID_Organizations        ,
                    @RBNR_Organizations     ,
                    @HeaderID       
                )
            End

            IF(@IsStructureEmpty = 0)
            Begin
                Insert into [dbo].[EQ_Structure]
                (
                    EquipmentNo,
                    HEQNR      ,
                    HEQUI      ,
                    POSNR      ,
                    SUBMT      ,
                    TIDNR      ,
                    TPLNR,
                    HeaderID

                )
                values 
                (
                    @EquipmentNo,
                    @HEQNR_Structure        ,
                    @HEQUI_Structure        ,
                    @POSNR_Structure        ,
                    @SUBMT_Structure        ,
                    @TIDNR_Structure        ,
                    @TPLNR_Structure,
                    @HeaderID
                )
            End

            IF(@IsSerialEmpty = 0)
            Begin
                Insert into [dbo].[EQ_Serial]
                (
                    B_CHARGE,
                    B_LAGER ,
                    B_WERK  ,
                    CHARGE  ,
                    LBBSA   ,
                    MATNR   ,
                    SERNR,
                    HeaderID
                

                )
                values 
                (
                    @B_CHARGE,
                    @B_LAGER    ,
                    @B_WERK ,
                    @CHARGE ,
                    @LBBSA  ,
                    @MATNR  ,
                    @SERNR,
                    @HeaderID
                )
            End
            

            IF(@IsWarrantyEmpty = 0)
            Begin
                Insert into [dbo].[EQ_Warranty]
                (
                    EquipmentNo     ,
                    GWLDT           ,
                    GWLDTSpecified  ,
                    GWLEN           ,
                    GWLENSpecified,
                    HeaderID

                )
                values 
                (
                    @EquipmentNo        ,
                    @GWLDT          ,
                    @GWLDTSpecified ,
                    @GWLEN          ,
                    @GWLENSpecified,
                    @HeaderID
                )
             End
            


            Declare @ClassificationTypeCount int
            Set @ClassificationTypeCount= (Select Count(*) from @ClassificationCollection)

            If(@ClassificationTypeCount > 0)
            Begin
                
                --Classification
                Insert into [dbo].Eq_Classification
                (
                    EquipmentNo,
                    CLASS,
                    KLTXT,
                    KLART,
                    HeaderID
                )
                --values 
                --(
                --  @EquipmentNo,
                --  @CLASS_Classification,
                --  @KLTXT_Classification,
                --  @KLART_Classification

                --)

                Select @EquipmentNo, CLASS, KLTXT, KLART, @HeaderID from @ClassificationCollection

                Declare @ClassificationID int
                Set @ClassificationID= IDENT_CURRENT('Eq_Classification')

                END

                --Characteristic

                Declare @CharacteristicTypeCount int
                Set @CharacteristicTypeCount= (Select Count(*) from @CharacteristicCollection)

                If(@CharacteristicTypeCount > 0)
                Begin
                
                    Insert into [dbo].EQ_Characteristic
                    (
                        EquipmentNo,
                        ATNAM,
                        ATZHL,
                        ATBEZ,
                        HeaderID,
                        ClassificationID

                    )
                    --values 
                    --(
                    --  @ATNAM_Characteristic,
                    --  @ATZHL_Characteristic,
                    --  @ATBEZ_Characteristic

                    --)

                    Select @EquipmentNo , ATNAM, ATZHL, ATBEZ, @HeaderID, @ClassificationID from @CharacteristicCollection
                END
                --Value

                Declare @ValueTypeCount int
                Set @ValueTypeCount= (Select Count(*) from @ValueCollection)

                If(@ValueTypeCount > 0)
                Begin
                
                    Insert into [dbo].EQ_Value
                    (
                        EquipmentNo,
                        ATWRT,
                        EINHE,
                        ATZHL,
                        HeaderID,
                        ClassificationID


                    )
                    --values 
                    --(
                    --  @EquipmentNo,
                    --  @ATWRT_Value,
                    --  @EINHE_Value,
                    --  @ATZHL_Value

                    --)

                    Select @EquipmentNo, ATWRT, EINHE, ATZHL, @HeaderID, @ClassificationID from @ValueCollection
            
                  End


            IF(ISNULL(@StatusRet , '') = '')
            Begin
                Set @STATUSRet= 'Created'
                Set @ErrorRet= ''
            End
            

        Commit Transaction

    End Try
    Begin Catch

        Set @STATUSRet= 'Failed'
        Set @ErrorRet= ( Select CAST(Error_Line() as Varchar(20)) + ':' +ERROR_MESSAGE())

        Rollback Transaction

    End Catch

END
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `SCOPE_IDENTITY` rather than `IDENT_CURRENT`. `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will give you the latest identity value inserted for the current session and current scope. Whereas `IDENT_CURRENT` will give you the value from the table across all sessions. If you have multiple clients calling this procedure concurrently it's possible that you could pick up the identity value from a different client.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your sproc is too long to totally parse like this, but I suspect that if this problem is intermittent, then you might find that the error is to do with this line:

```
Set @HeaderID= IDENT_CURRENT('EQ_Header') --Latest Header ID
```

You should probably read this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

And specifically this section:

> IDENT_CURRENT is similar to the SQL Server 2000 (8.x) identity
> functions SCOPE_IDENTITY and @@IDENTITY. All three functions return
> last-generated identity values. However, the scope and session on
> which last is defined in each of these functions differ:
>
> IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value generated for a specific
> table in any session and any scope.
>
> @@IDENTITY returns the last
> identity value generated for any table in the current session, across
> all scopes.
>
> SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated
> for any table in the current session and the current scope.

You are currently getting the last generated ID for that table for *any scope and any session*.  You should probably change it to SCOPE_IDENTITY.

Comment: ok so scope identity won't cause any problem? like I heard it would pick the last identity from any table?

Comment: how would scope_identity know that it has to be picked from the EQ_Header table.

Comment: `scope_identity` will show you the last identity value inserted in the current scope (i.e. the proc). As long as you have it as the next statement in the batch it will give you the identity number from the last table you inserted into - which is safer than using `IDENT_CURRENT` which could give you the identity number from a different session.

Comment: If you are uncertain as to its function, can I suggest that the documentation should let you know exactly what it does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Sean  (SELECT  SCOPE_IDENTITY())

Comment: is this ok instead of the IDENT_CURRENT?

Comment: select @HeaderId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()